# How can I display item Titles from a Sharepoint list in c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Here's my function that works, but I can figure out how to specifically display an item title in the listbox.

```html
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("myurl"))
  {
    ctx.Credentials = CredentialsFactory.SharePointCredentials.CreateCredentials(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, CredentialsFactory.SharePointCredentials.SharePointAuthentication.SharePointOnline);
    List clinicsList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Clinics");
    CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(1000);
    ListItemCollection clinics = clinicsList.GetItems(query);
    ctx.Load(clinics);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    listBox1.DataSource = clinics.ToList();
  }
}
```

I'm sure this is really simple!  Thanks in advance!

Here is a screenshot of the output.

[image]

Comment: What is the result you are getting in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You need `ListItem` from `ListItemCollection`

```
// Show item in text box
ListItemCollection clinics = clinicsList.GetItems(query);
 foreach (ListItem item in clinics)
  {
  ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Title);
  }
```

I hope this will help you